# How can customize stack bar graph style in google sheets with google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, embedded-resource

I need to change style in stacked bar graph in google sheets with app script. I don't know if is it possible. I try EmbededChart, specialy the `.setOption` but don't exactly match with the result expected.

Change each colors for every stacked bar depending of somes conditions. Change thickness, bold etc...

The most important is to display text in each bar properly.

I know is it possible with google charts but i don't want this, i really need to display it in google sheets.

To resume, if anyone know if is it possible to customize style stacked bar chart in google sheets with google apps scripts, i really appreciate :)

```
// maybe others options are available  for setOption() ?

chart = chart.modify()
    .addRange(range)
    .setOption('title', 'Updated!')
    .setOption('animation.duration', 500) 
    .setPosition(2,2,0,0)
    .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
```